# Is there anyway to use the Windows UI Library with a python GUI framework

Tags: python, tkinter, winapi, kivy, devexpress-windows-ui

Essentially I am trying to create a very simple app that has the GUI of a standard windows 10 app. But the GUI elements that come with Tkinter or Kivy (python bassed GUI builders) seem very outdated and not suited to windows 10. Is there any way to use the Windows UI Library with one of those so I can build the app in python but still have the visual impression of a windows 10 app? Or will I have to learn C# or C++ to use the Windows UI Library? Any other Windows UI Library alternatives that basically do the same thing, that work with python will also be fine thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of [ttk](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes) ? Ttk is designed to give you native looking widgets and options to design your style. Compare it to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-types-and-styles)

Comment: @Atlas435 so is there noway to use the windows ui library with python ?

Comment: It is, google for win32gui. But most commonly one uses a toolkit to avoid these massive code if there isnt a good reason for. But you could work your way through if you really want to.

Comment: @Atlas435 right but what is actually in charge of the GUI elements like the buttons, how can I just use the normal windows buttons (for instance the next button on an installer wizard) with Tkinter or kivy to build the GUI ?